Changing the header of a Column using javascript
I have a strange requirement that involves changing the headers of columns within an interactive grid from a popup LOV page item without the need to submit/reload the page every time the parameter changes.
My first thought was to have some javascript code that messes with the headers that gets executed from a Dynamic Action.  Here is the code I have so far:
var parts_arr = $v("P200_PARTS_SELECTION").split(':'),
  col_staticID_arr = ['#part-1_HDR', '#part-2_HDR', '#part-3_HDR', '#part-4_HDR', '#part-5_HDR',
    '#part-6_HDR', '#part-7_HDR', '#part-8_HDR', '#part-9_HDR', '#part-10_HDR'
  ];

for (let i = 0, len = parts_arr.count; i < len; i++) {
  $(col_staticID_arr[i]).text(apex.item("P200_PARTS_SELECTION").displayValueFor(parts_arr[i]));
};

This unfortunately does not work for a few reasons, firstly it seems that I can't use a variable or even a concatenated string in the $(...).text field.  Secondly, the displauValueFor(...) field only seems to pull the display value of P200_PARTS_SELECTION when it only holds one value.
However I believe I am on the right path because the following line of code DOES successfully change the header of the column:
$('#part-1_HDR').text('TEST');

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You seem to be using jQuery. Please tag accordingly. You should really also show some HTML. Please see [ask].



let arr = $(".text").text().split(':');
let col_arr = ['#part-1', '#part-2', '#part-3'];

$('th').each(function( index ) {
  $(col_arr[index]).html(arr[index]);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">text1:text2:text3</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="part-1">Column 1</th>
      <th id="part-2">Column 2</th>
      <th id="part-3">Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 1, Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 2, Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Column 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



I made this exemple. This may be work in your case.

I'm relatively new to APEX and I'm a bit confused, the second block of code looks like HTML, where should I put this?

Nowhere. I just used the snipet to show you the exemple. You can simply copy the JS

If that is the case, what is value used for? am I supposed to substitute something in for that? and does my page item get referenced where you put ".text"?

You can run the snipet and see for yourself

Well the snippit does not appear to do anything

Look at the table header on the HTML. The js is changing the values.

The column headings are in the column metadata. So an approach could also be to adjust this metadata and refresh the grid (this won't do a reload, only redrawing as per current state).
Example code:
let gridView = apex.region('ig_dept').widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid");
let columns = gridView.getColumns();
let dnameColumn = columns.filter(column => column.elementId == 'c_dname')[0];   // filter by staticId
//let dnameColumn = columns.filter(column => column.property == 'DNAME')[0];   // filter by column name 
dnameColumn.heading = 'Dept name';
gridView.refreshColumns();
gridView.refresh();


This solution seems promising, but I am having trouble looping it so that I can change many columns as the column.elementId field doesn't seem to take a variable.  Also I would like for the JS to grab the display values of the page item I listed above if possible

You can check elementId for fixed value or variable value. Wrt popup lov, you can only get the display value for current selected value. What you might try is load the values in a (hidden) select list and use displayValueFor() on that page item as for select list you can ask the displayValue for any value.
